# To customize the list of an AutocompleteTextView

Tags: android, listview, autocompletetextview

Hi I'm trying to create an AutoCompleteTextView. The resulting list of this AutoCompleteTextView should be placed below the dit text. Can anyone please help me how I can achieve this?

Comment: where is your image?

Comment: You have to use custom adapter, extending `BaseAdapter` for instance, and create your own view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the question, it looks like you need to show the results in a separate list.
So, Assuming your `EditText` is called as searchText and assuming your `ListAdapter` is called as searchAdapter, Then set `addTextChangedListener` to the `EditText`.

```
EditText searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

       }

       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

       }

       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           searchAdapter.filter(s.toString());
       }
});
```

And then in the `ListAdapter`, add a filter function to filter from the dataset using the keyword entered.

```
private List<String> titles, titlesCopy;
//keep a copy of your dataset
public void filter(String charText) {
   charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
   titles.clear();
   if (charText.length() == 0) {
      titles.addAll(titlesCopy); //no text entered, so add all results
   } else {
      for (String filtered : titlesCopy) { //check with keyword from the copy data set
          if (filtered.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                titles.add(filtered);
          }
      }
   }
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPurpose"
    android:layout_width="370dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:dropDownHeight="300dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"/>
```

and use `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,` as a design for the list that you want to fill

I hope this will help you solving what you want, and let me know if it didn't work.